# Opencv iOS install

Tags: python, ios, opencv, installation, cmake

Opencv for iOS wont work on my Mac 
I've done this steps

1.Downloaded cmake

2.installed and runned it(opened ".dmg" and install)

3.`cd ~/documents`

4.`git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git`

It startet downloading and a Folder appeared

5.`cd /`

6.`sudo on -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer Developer`

7.`cd ~/documents`

8.`python opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py ios`

I now get the error:

```
Executing: cmake -GXcode -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/Maxi/Documents/opencv/platforms/ios/cmake/Toolchains/Toolchain-iPhoneOS_Xcode.cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-Wno-implicit-function-declaration" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install -DENABLE_NEON=ON -DBUILD_opencv_world=ON /Users/Maxi/Documents/opencv
/bin/sh: cmake: command not found
('Child returned:', 127)
```

Thanks in advance

Ps: Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.2, Xcode 6.1.1, cmake 3.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing from either of the repositories [**brew**](http://brew.sh/) or [**macports**](https://www.macports.org/).

Comment: Do not go this route.

Comment: @JamesBush Why not?  If not this route then which?  Your comment seems incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Cmake is missing

```
/bin/sh: cmake: command not found
```

You just have to install it correctly (link it).

Comment: Use CocoaPods, then change the extension .m to .mm for every implementation file that uses OpenCV. You'll have the latest version, and in five minutes and just two steps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need OpenCV iOS Framework, You can just download the framework from the OpenCV portal.
[Download OpenCV](http://opencv.org/downloads.html)

Or You can build from Mac. In your command sequence, You have not install CMAKE. Check the below link for installing CMAKE.
[Process of Installing CMAKE in MAC.](http://tudat.tudelft.nl/projects/tudat/wiki/Install_on_Mac_OS_X) Then execute the command which you have done before. Problem will be solved.

Comment: Do not go this route.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use POD for OpenCV , it is easy and simple.

[LINK](https://cocoapods.org/?q=opencv)